# Ruby Savon SOAP - Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, soap, savon

I'm trying to consume a webservice, to get a session ID. And after that i will consume another webservice.

Here is the service specs:

https://xml.reserve.com.br/1.16/autenticacao.asmx

I have almost no experience with Ruby, but i'm trying to learn to get this job done.

I'm using Ruby 2.2 and Savon 2.11.

Here is my code:

```
require 'savon'

client = Savon.client(soap_version: 2, wsdl:    "http://xml.reserve.com.br/1.16/autenticacao.asmx?WSDL")

puts client.operations

puts "\n"

resposta = client.call(:autenticar, xml: {Usuario: "XXX", Senha: "XXX"})

puts resposta
```

After that i'm getting the following error:

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/savon-   2.11.1/lib/savon/response.rb:85:in `raise_soap_and_http_errors!':   (soap:Receiver) Server was unable to process request. ---> Data at the root   level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. (Savon::SOAPFault)
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/savon-  2.11.1/lib/savon/response.rb:14:in `initialize'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/operation.rb:72:in `new'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/operation.rb:72:in `create_response'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/operation.rb:58:in `call'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/client.rb:36:in `call'
from C:/Users/mateus.leitao/RubymineProjects/untitled/reserve:9:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: have you tried changing this `xml: {Usuario: "XXX", Senha: "XXX"}` to `message: {Usuario: "XXX", Senha: "XXX"}` since that is what Savon is expecting per the documentation. [Docs](http://savonrb.com/version2/client.html). If you want to pass xml then it needs to a properly formed xml string. [Source Code](https://github.com/savonrb/savon/blob/master/lib/savon/options.rb#L397)

Comment: Yes, i have tried. When i try with :message i got this error :

   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/savon-  2.11.1/lib/savon/response.rb:85:in `raise_soap_and_http_errors!':   (soap:Receiver) Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (Savon::SOAPFault)